# How do I make linspace work for small numbers?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use linspace in Matlab for small numbers, e.g. from 0.00003 to 0.1.

However, if I do this, the first number/bin is not 0.00003, but 0, which does not give me an equal distribution:

> > linspace(0.00003,0.1,10)

ans =

```
0.0000    0.0111    0.0222    0.0334    0.0445    0.0556    0.0667    0.0778    0.0889    0.1000
```

I realized that if I start with 0.0003 or larger then it works, but how can I make it work for smaller numbers?

Answer (score 3):

This is purely due to the way that the [MATLAB command window is displaying your data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html?refresh=true).

The default way that numbers are displayed is the [`short` format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#input_argument_style) which the documentation states is:

> Short, fixed-decimal format with 4 digits after the decimal point

Your first data point doesn't have a non-zero digit until the 5th digit after the decimal point so it simply shows up as `0.0000`.

Try changing the [display format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#input_argument_style) to something that will show more significant digits. You can do this using `format`.

```
format long g
```

Also, in the future, if you actually want to check that something is behaving as you expect, do an *explicit* check by value not just by trusting what shows up in the command window.

```
limit = 0.000003
data = linsapce(limit, 0.1, 10);

% Check that the first datapoint is "equal" to what you expect
assert(abs(data(1) - limit) < eps)
```

Comment: I'd caution against comparing floats for equality

Comment: @user3261573 If that worked for you, please consider marking this as an answer.